# Publish multiple web.configs with dotnet publish

Tags: .net, iis, .net-core, azure-devops, blazor

I am using Blazor WASM and I will be setting the environment variable via the `web.config` server header. However I want to be able to transform the `web.config` on deployment via the Azure DevOps IIS Web deploy task. How can I get the `dotnet publish` command to publish both the main `web.config` and the transform `web.Release.config`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to publish with a transformation of web.config file with **dotnet publish**, you can just set --configuration options for "release".
For example,

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release
```

Build configuration transforms are run first.

Besides, you can also include **Profile**, **Environment** and **Custom transformations** after Build configuration transforms.

More details, you can refer to below links:

[Transform web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Web.config File Transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations)

[dotnet publish Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish)